# Confused about "tree" not finding a file

Tags: linux, tree

Why the last **tree** is not finding **fstab**?

```
tree /etc -P fstab --prune
/etc
└── fstab    
0 directories, 1 file
```

.

```
tree /etc -P fsta* --prune
/etc
└── fstab
0 directories, 1 file
```

.

```
tree /etc -P *stab --prune
/etc
└── fstab    
0 directories, 1 file
```

**What is happening here?**
According to my understanding it should find *at least* `fstab`

```
tree /etc -P *sta* --prune   
/etc
0 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Do you have a filename matching `*sta*` in the current directory? Since the pattern is unquoted, it would expand to that name (or those names).

Comment: To the downvoter: if somebody asks "why" it means he/she didn't understand. A missed info in `man` (in my case that I need to use the quotes) should NEVER cause downvotes. I don't personally care, but some newbies could think that stackoverflow is only for the "elite" and the experts. I didn't feel the need of quotes because `*stab` and `fsta*` are indeed working properly without them. Kusalananda answered to my "why". This is what I expect from Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use an unquoted globbing pattern on the command line, the shell will try to match it against filenames.  If no filename matches the pattern, most shells will keep the unexpanded pattern (`zsh` would by default complain, as would `bash` with `set -u`).

You obviously have some file whose name matches `*sta*`, but not `fsta*` or `*stab`. The shell expands `*sta*` to the name of that file, which means that the pattern no longer matches `fstab` under `/etc`.

The solution is to use single or double quotes around the pattern (and let `tree` do its own pattern matching internally).